# Slate JS: set the prop as the Editor's value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

I am building an textarea email form using Slate JS editor. Instead of slate default initial state value, I would like to display my own value which is passed to the component as a prop from redux.

So instead of this:

```
        <Editor
    spellCheck
    autoFocus
    placeholder="Enter your text..."
    ref={this.ref}
    **value = {this.state.value}**
    onPaste={this.onPaste}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    renderNode={this.renderNode}
    renderMark={this.renderMark}
    />
```

I am doing this:

```
        <Editor
    spellCheck
    autoFocus
    placeholder="Enter your text..."
    ref={this.ref}
    **value = {Value.fromJSON(JSON.stringify(this.props.richText))}**
    onPaste={this.onPaste}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    renderNode={this.renderNode}
    renderMark={this.renderMark}
    />
```

So that prop is passed as an object, converted first to json and then to required slate editor format. That doesn't break the component but the value is not displayed in the editor. What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to set up the slate editor value as a prop? Thank you for any help with this!

Comment: Try removing the JSON.stringify method call, according to the docs the required type is an object and not a json string https://docs.slatejs.org/slate-core/value#value-fromjson

Comment: I was thinking about that too. That Value.fromJSON requires the passed object to be a string/JSON object

Comment: After taking a look at https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/master/examples/rich-text/index.js#L42, they pass in an object (imported at L5) instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

The `value` in Slate is much more than just the value of a text field, and basically stores all the data about the Slate editor.

To pass in data from props, you need to deserialize `this.props.richText` and store it in state, and then update state's `value` every time `Editor` changes. Here's how you'd do that if you want a plain text editor.

```
import { Editor } from 'slate-react'
import Plain from 'slate-plain-serializer'
​
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: Plain.deserialize(this.props.richText),
  }
​
  onChange = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({ value })
  }
​
  render() {
    return <Editor value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
  }
}
```

If you want a rich text or html editor, the deserialization is a little more involved, but pretty straightforward if you follow these guides:

- [Saving and Loading HTML Content](https://docs.slatejs.org/walkthroughs/saving-and-loading-html-content)
- Rich text [example](https://www.slatejs.org/#/rich-text) &
  [code](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/master/examples/rich-text/index.js)